# Hiding Outlook LDAP-Error if Recipient not resolved (C#)

Tags: c#, outlook, ldap, resolve

My problem is that when I try to resolve a recipient with a name that doesn't exist, Outlook opens a new window: LDAP-Error. Is there any chance to keep Outlook from doing that? I would like to show my own error-message instead.

That's my code:

```
string rec = "LastName, FirstName";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient r = createRecipient(rec);
r.Resolve();
```

I think that's probably very easy, I just couldn't find out anything myself.
Is there an Exception to catch?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: sorry, i forgot that one.

```
using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
private static OutLook._Application _outlookObj = new OutLook.Application();
private static OutLook._NameSpace _nameSpace = _outlookObj.GetNamespace("MAPI");

public OutLook.Recipient createRecipient(string rec)
    {
        OutLook.Recipient r = _nameSpace.CreateRecipient(rec);
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your createRecipient function?